# How does NFT lazy minting actually works?

Tags: nft, erc-721, lazy-mint

So I am trying to understand lazy minting in NFTs and till now I have understood the whole NFT Voucher concept that we have to create vouchers offline and the user buying the NFTs will then redeem this voucher and mint the NFT (Correct me if I am wrong).

But my question is how will marketplaces like Opensea and Rarible show those NFTs on their platform since there has been no mint or no Transfer event has been emitted? I did find that adding NFT to a lazy mint directly from the Marketplace works fine, but how will it work from the contract side. Any answer would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same question too

Comment: Apparently, NFT vouchers work on the client's platform only. It means that whenever a person wants to build his own marketplace, the vouchers will work there only. They will not be shown on Open sea, etc.

Comment: Interesting...not sure how `opensea` and `rarible` can show those NFT.

Comment: @JohnJoe They won't. `Opensea` and `rarible` can only show those NFTs after they are minted.

Comment: thanks you ....